# How to use Windows network card drivers in Kali Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux, network-adapter

I bought a wireless network adapter so I put it in my Windows PC, I installed the driver automatically by an `.exe` program that installed in it; then I installed Kali Linux (last version) to start practice some programming codes in Kali Linux software (installed by Oracle VM Virtual Box), but when I start Kali Linux I surprised with the wireless network adapter not working, I tried to run `lsusb` command to see if Kali Linux recognized it or not and it's showing me good news:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

but when I write `iwconfig` command to see the internet wireless config if its monitor mode or not and I know that it's will be managed it's showing me:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I thought that this is because the automatic driver installer or the driver mainly so I read the manual of product to download driver in original product website but failed, opened ChatGPT to ask it anything that will be good and that failed. I came up with convert that `.exe` program to the driver file to use it in Kali Linux software in Oracle VM Virtual Box so I installed `UniExtract` program to convert the `.exe` file program to the driver files. Then the last move is convert driver files to be suitable for Kali Linux software then moving it from Windows to Kali Linux software in Oracle VM Virtual Box -> not finished.

I asked ChatGPT again and it suggested to install `ndiswrapper` to move the files to Kali Linux software and convert it to be ran by Kali Linux software, but failed. I understood that `ndiswrapper` is removed from Kali Linux software and now I'm searching "outside the box"; I need another way to use Windows network card drivers in Kali Linux software.

Please help me!

Information about the wireless network adapter:

- Modem: BL-WDN650A
- On Windows 10 64x: Working
- On Kali Linux software installed on Oracle VM Virtual Box: Not working

Comment: *Kali Linux(Last Version) to start practice some programming codes* Kali is NOT for that. Please read https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ . Then read about virtualization and your specific solution (Virtualbox) in order to understand what virtualized hardware is and how it works. In a nutshell, you don't use it like you think it does. Finally, even if it were Kali or any other distro installed in bare metal you wouldn't be looking for Windows drivers.

Comment: And also read about how drivers work and why attempting to convert an `.exe` installer to work with Kali is a very terrible idea. I wouldn't also trust ChatGPT with such issues if that's what it suggested to you (but then it could have been partially a language problem as your English isn't perfect)

Comment: Thanks but..
First I mean by practice some programming codes that I practice programming codes that I learned before like "airmon-ng" or something like "airodump-ng"
Second I download the driver of it in the original product website but its not working there is a lot of problems and you can see on google just type the model of the wireless network adapter + kali linux
and finally I'm new thanks for you comment <3

Comment: Please use proper formatting in your question. It is currently very hard to read. // Even among Linux compatible cards, not all of them are compatible with the tools you want to use. You must use compatible hardware with native drivers.

Comment: Ok, dont worry and thanks you helped me a lot

Comment: must I make it clear and compatible?

Comment: airodump is used to brute force the security of wireless access points and only support specific wireless WAN adapters. Are you positive you have compatible hardware? Instead of submitting additional commentary, edit your question, and clarify your question while improving the grammar of your question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Drivers, in general terms, allow a specific OS to understand and communicate with specific hardware.

All of the things that make OSes different from each other mean that the drivers written for one will not work with another.

Where OSes share architecture there MAY be a SMALL CHANCE a driver may work on an OS different from the one it was written for, but the shared components must be integral parts of the OS architecture. Apple's OS X being based on Unix at its core would be an example of this.

Windows shares no architectural components with Kali Linux. You cannot do what you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed the extension pack for virtual box? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
if not install it then in you virtual box manager in Os settings
Go to usb and add usb 2.0 and add the wifi adapter